# Petapoco - Can't auto join

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, orm, petapoco, micro-orm

I have an object call Country and another call CounytryRegions as express below

```
[TableName("Countries"),
PrimaryKey("Code", autoIncrement = false)]
public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.CountryRegions = new List<CountryRegion>();
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Foliaco.DataAccess.ResultColumn()]
    public List<CountryRegion> CountryRegions { get; set; }

}

[TableName("CountryRegions"),
PrimaryKey("Code", autoIncrement = false)]
public class CountryRegion 
{
    public CountryRegion()
    {
        this.Country = new Country();
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Foliaco.DataAccess.ResultColumn()]
    public Country Country { get; set; }

}
```

If I execute the sql below

```
 Country country = this.DB.Fetch<Country,CountryRegion>("select * from dbo.countries c join dbo.countryregions cr on c.Code = cr.CountryCode where c.Code = @0","US").FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm expecting to get on the CountryRegions property of the Country class all the associated records to that country, but instead I getting the get following Error

Can't auto join CountryRegion

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think I found the problem according with thier documentation I need to crated a Relator Class to load the list. [link](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/115/PetaPoco-Mapping-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-One-Relationships) refer to section One to Many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem according with their documentation I need to crated a Realtor Class to load the list refer to section One to Many on the [Petapoco Documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/115/PetaPoco-Mapping-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-One-Relationships), I've also found this helper class [OneTOMany](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2011/08/21/petapoco-one-to-many-and-many-to-one/) that makes the Realtor class more generic

Comment: Petapoco is great when you want to do stuff that you don't do in the real world, but as soon as you do good luck buddy.

Comment: ..and this is why you should provide code and not a link :(

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error using the NPoco library, which is based on PetaPoco.

The problem in my case was I was calling `.Fetch` instead of `.FetchOneToMany`.